# reading csv to dataframe with dynamic custom schema with pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm working with databricks in a notebook. I want to read csv files with custom schema.
I'd like to be able to loop over all the csv files in a folder and read them with their respective schema.

So I have a schema for each csv file:

```
csv_1 = StructType([
    StructField('foo', StringType(), False),
    StructField('bar', StringType(), True),
])

csv_2 = StructType([
    StructField('foo', StringType(), False),
    StructField('bar', StringType(), True),
    StructField('baz', StringType(), True),
])

csv_3 = StructType([
    StructField('bar', StringType(), True)
])
```

Then I have this loop:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    dataframes[filename] = spark.read.csv(path+file, header=True, schema=???)
```

I guess I probably need to use some mapping somewhere but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
filename_to_related_mapping = {
  'name1': csv_1,
  'name2': csv_2,
 ...
}.get(filename)
```

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    dataframes[filename] = spark.read.csv(path+file, header=True, schema=filename_to_related_mapping[filename])
```

Anyway its just a CSV, another way is not pass the schema and it will be infered dynamically.

Comment: yes you're right but then I'm checking for null values.